# Getting FME to write features in order provided?

Tags: fme-form

I have a simple model that just does a series of queries/data cleanups and then puts the data into a csv. Unfortunately it's being put into the CSV in a random order.

How can I get it to write in order?

[image]

Running this I get

[image]

But I need it to be Lot Plan, then Prop No, Land No, Street address and finally toilets.

Based on https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/40473/is-it-possible-to-make-a-transformer-wait-for-the.html I added a connection run time order but still get the same output.

[image]

I am using the current ver of FME desktop.

**UPDATE:**

Here's what worked. [image]

Comment: have you tried the sorter transformer before the writer? if needed you can create a temporary attribute to sort on.

Comment: I hadn't but have done it now and it works. So I just add tOrder and put in value 1-5 and then sorted by that and it worked. If you want to add as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Sorter](https://www.safe.com/transformers/sorter/) transformer before the writer. It will output features in sorted order against the selected attribute(s).